# Prevent reading a certain collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have many collections for reading, but they are not allowed to write. I also have one collection where reading is prohibited, but writing is allowed. How to do this correctly?
I tried many ways to correctly prescribe the rules. The official documentation did not solve my problem.

It should work on this principle:

```
match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if false;
    }
match /FOLDER/FOLDER {
      allow read: if false;
      allow write: if true;
    }
```

But it does not work because Overlapping match statements.
"In the case where multiple allow expressions match a request, the access is allowed if any of the conditions is true"

Tried also with `exists` and `get`.

There are no common fields between these collections.

How to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Since this rule grants unconditional read access to your entire database:

```
match /{document=**} {
  allow read: if true;
  allow write: if false;
}
```

You can't use it at all if you don't want some of your collections to have read access.  You should remove that rule, and write new rules *for each of the collections where you do want to allow access*.

You could also try omitting the one unreadable collection from the global rule, but I don't recommend this, as it's less clear what you're trying to do:

```
match /{document=**} {
  allow read: if document[0] != "unreadable-collection";
  allow write: if false;
}
```